# Can you get value from SubReport?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have a SubReport with a textbox, I would like to read the value of this textbox and then put it in the main report for each data row.

My SubReport is in a data column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to drag and drop the sub report object into the text box and configure it from there. But make sure that if the sub report expects parameters, you send the required parameters.